# Please add a "self answer" flag to the answer results/object

Tags: feature-request, api, answers

Is there an easy way to tell if an answer is from the question poster?

I'm working on [Blaze](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/Blaze), and I'm grabbing answers from the `/answers` method. I'd like to indicate if the answer is from the question author.

I can't find a field on the answer to easily tell if it's from the asker.  It seems to require multiple API calls. What's the cheapest way to do this?

**Please add an `is_self_answer` field to [the `answer` object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/answer).**

Comment: Until the feature request goes through, you will have to also query the `/questions/{ids}` path to determine if the Q & A are posted by the same user.